# Bootstrap: How to design Conditional Button Group like Semantic UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, semantic-ui

In my web page, I would like to have a group of two buttons e.g. `Add More` or `Save All`.

I am using Bootstrap 3 for designing the page. Now I know Bootstrap allows button groups which will look like this:

[image: Bootstrap Button Groups]

But recently I visited the [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html#conditionals) and saw awesome button group which looks like the below image:

[image: Semantic Button Group]

***Can I design similar button groups (with conditional 'OR' in a circle in the middle) using Bootstrap? If yes, how?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here is the game, just have to inspect the element....*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/j4xkdrVPWZ

**HTML** :

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">Left</button>
  <div class="or"></div>
  <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.or {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: .3em;
  height: 2.57142em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.or:before {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 500rem;
  content: 'or';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
  margin-top: -.892855em;
  margin-left: -.892855em;
  width: 1.78571em;
  height: 1.78571em;
  line-height: 1.78571em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent inset;
}
```